# extend the duration/execution time of ansible command

Tags: ansible

```
- name: 'TASK 1: Debug'
  aireos_command: 
     commands:
       - 'debug client <mac address>'
  register: debug
```

i have this command and how can i keep this command running for about 5 minutes instead of ending it as soon as the command has been configured. Wanted to keep this command running so we can capture necessary logs in 5 minute duration

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation of Cisco Wireless LAN Controller (WLC) Command Reference, there seems to be no `sleep` of `wait` there.

But according description of [`aireos_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/network/aireos_command_module.html) you might be able to introduce additional parameters [`interval`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/network/aireos_command_module.html#parameters), [`match`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/network/aireos_command_module.html#parameters), and [`retries`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/network/aireos_command_module.html#parameters) to achieve your goal.